# GET img/png with grails.plugins.rest.client.RestResponse

Tags: rest, grails, png

I am using grails.plugins.rest.client.RestResponse to GET a binary resource of content-type png from a rest endpoint.

```
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestResponse

String url = "http://localhost:8080/rest-endpoint/image.png"
RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
RestResponse restResponse = rest.get(url){
    auth username, password
    accept "image/png"
    contentType "image/png"
}

byte[] png_image = restResponse.responseEntity.body
println "length " + png_image.length
```

I'm not sure why the length that is returned is ~500bytes less than expected and I have tried with a different image and a different url and the length returned is lower everytime. Any idea why?

Comment: check the `"Content-Length"` in response header

Comment: Can you try to save it and recheck sizes again? Maybe it is some meta information that didn't send.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and ended up using `HTTPBuilder` instead.

```
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.Method

class RestUtil {

    static byte[] getBytes(String url) {
        new HTTPBuilder(url).request(Method.GET, ContentType.BINARY) {
            requestContentType = ContentType.BINARY
            response.success = { resp, binary ->
                return binary.bytes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that's helpful.